# node.js - logging in won't update to show username

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, authentication, pug

I have a Node.js app that I am using to build a login system. I have the login system working, but I have to manually refresh the page for it to show 'username logged in'. It successfully hides the sign in/sign up fields that you need to fill out to log in.

Here is my app.js code:

```
/**
  * Application Configuration
  */
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.enable('jsonp callback');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.set('view options', {layout : false});
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({
    secret : 'sessionsecret'      
  }));
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
  });
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

And here is the part of `login.js` where I am hiding the login form.

```
    if(username && password){
      $.post('/login', $(this).serialize(), function(response){
        if(response.retStatus === 'success'){
          $('#loginForm').hide();
          $('#signup-btn').hide();
          //$(location).attr('href', '/admin');
        }else if(response.retStatus === 'failure'){
          $('#signup-error-modal').modal('show');
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

And finally this is the JADE/HTML code for the view where it should be showing the username automatically

```
if(session.user)
        div#logoutsection.pull-right
          a#logout-btn.btn.btn-info.pull-right.top-bar-form-button(href='/logout') Logout
          p#loginprompt.pull-right.login-prompt #{session.user.username} 
            small logged In
      else
        a#signup-btn.btn.pull-right.top-bar-form-button(href='#signup-modal', data-toggle="modal") Sign Up
        form.pull-right.form-horizontal.top-bar-form(method="post", id="loginForm")
          input.input-small.top-bar-form-textbox(id="username", type="text", name="User", placeholder="Username")
          input.input-small.top-bar-form-textbox(id="password", type="password", name="Password", placeholder="Password")
          button.btn.btn-primary.top-bar-form-button(type="submit", value="Sign In") Sign In
```

Let me know if you want to see anymore code, I think I have it all here. But I really don't get why I have to manually refresh for it to show the username. Any ideas welcome?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that although you have the username being displayed if the session has a user on it on the jade/html file. It won't update automatically with the Ajax response. Instead what you have to do is to update the html within the ajax success function.

That is on your login.js file, something similar to this:

```
if(username && password){
      $.post('/login', $(this).serialize(), function(response){
        if(response.retStatus === 'success'){
          $('#loginForm').hide();
          $('#signup-btn').hide();
          // Add the name of the user to the html here!
          // Edit: If you don't want to send the username from node.js
          $("p#loginprompt").html(username);
        }else if(response.retStatus === 'failure'){
          $('#signup-error-modal').modal('show');
        }
      });
    }
```

Note that the paragraph element should exist on the DOM before appending to it. And that the username should be sent by the server on the response and sanitized to avoid Cross-site scripting attacks.

Other non-user friendly way to do it is to programmatically refresh the page. But please don't do it this way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand what you are doing, sending to the `p#loginprompt` the username, I added this line and I still have to refresh manually, I'm thinking the `.html(response.username)` may not be correct for what my case

Comment: And sorry, but I don't follow with the DOM and avoiding cross-site scripting attacks.

Comment: It doesn't work because you have to append the username to the response from Node.js. But If you don't want to do modify your code on the server side you can always do this:

`$("p#loginprompt").html(username);`

With the DOM I mean that the paragraph element you want to modify, in this case `p#loginprompt` should be already created before you try to sent the username to it.

Comment: Yes this still doesn't work. I can only get it to work at the moment by refreshing the whole page with `$(location).attr('href', '/');`